# Laravel whereRaw with a few parameters

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

Using Laravel 5.4 I am trying to run this query that gets me results on phpMyAdmin:

```
select * from `orders`
inner join `users` on `user_id` = `users`.`id`
where `status` = ?
and (`orders`.`id` LIKE ? or `first_name` LIKE ? or `last_name` LIKE ? or `company` LIKE ?
```

The problem is, although I get results in phpMyAdmin I get an empty result in the code.

I tried two ways:

```
    $orders =  Order::join('users', 'user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->whereRaw("status = ? and (orders.id LIKE '%?%' or first_name LIKE '%?%' or last_name LIKE '%?%' or company LIKE '%?%')", 
[$status, $search, $search, $search, $search])->get();
```

And

```
    $orders =  Order::join('users', 'user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->whereRaw("status = :status and 
(orders.id LIKE :search_id or first_name LIKE :search_first or last_name LIKE :search_last or company LIKE :search_company)", 
    ['status'=>$status, 'search_id'=>$search, 'search_first'=>$search, 'search_last'=>$search, 'search_company'=>$search])
    ->get();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this like this:

```
$search = '%' . $request->input('search.value') . '%'; 

        $orders =  Order::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
                ->whereRaw("status = ? and (orders.id LIKE ? or first_name LIKE ? or last_name LIKE ? or company LIKE ?)",[$status, $search, $search, $search, $search])
```